# What's the difference between "an operation" and "a surgery"

Tags: word-difference

What is the difference between "an operation" and "a surgery"?

Comment: In what context?  Specifically medical or more general English usage?

Comment: In medical usage.

Comment: Please include the definitions you've found that seem the same to you.

Comment: surgery: medical treatment in which a doctor cuts into someone's body in order to repair or remove damaged or diseased parts

Comment: operation: a  process in which a doctor cuts into someone's body in order to repair or remove a damaged or diseased part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In British English, as spoken by the medical profession, the word *operation* is obsolescent.

A *surgery* is both a place where a discussion with a patient takes place and the discussion itself.

Anything that the doctor does to the patient is a *procedure*.  This covers both non-invasive and invasive treatments.  It also covers both investigations and treatments.

Most non-medical people however will still use the term *operation* to refer to an invasive procedure where a surgeon treats a patient in a theatre.  Again, the term *operating theatre* is now less commonly used.

Comment: *Operating theatre* is used in teaching hospitals where students can observe the procedure as it takes place.

Comment: People other than doctors can hold a surgery.  For example, MPs hold constituency surgeries to enable constituents to obtain information and seek assistance.

Answer (score 4):

- An operation: a specific surgical procedure carried out on a patient.
- A surgery (British): A doctor's office or practice.
- A surgery (American & Canadian): A place where surgeries are performed, also called an operating room or operating theater.

[Reference](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/surgery).

Comment: I've never heard (here in the US) *surgery* used to refer to the operating room or to the section of the hospital where surgeries are performed. Cambridge dictionary of American English says it refers to the offices of the surgical practice, and I've never heard that usage here either.

Comment: The question was specifically about "a surgery," which is familiar to my American ears and supported by the reference. Dueling dictionaries? Regional variation?

Answer (score 3):

In American English, we would say:

I had an operation.

or

I had surgery.

Not "a surgery".

They mean the same.

Comment: Do you happen to know why surgery is countable when referring to a doctor's consultation, but uncountable when referring to an operation? Does this make sense to native speakers?

Comment: As in "Our surgical practice performed over 2000 abdominal surgeries in the last six months."?

Comment: Yes. Or as in "Is there a surgery this morning".

Comment: When a particular type of surgery is involved, then it becomes countable.  "He's had three elbow surgeries to repair the damage done to his arm while pitching ten entire games with insufficient rest."

Comment: In your example, it means "a surgery of any type", so the idea of "type of surgery" is still there.

Comment: Sorry, I had edited the comment, which may have confused you. So you would say "I need knee surgery", but "I had three knee surgeries"?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. (I hit the wrong button a moment ago.)